# exact line search in Newton's method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I was studying Newton's method recently, and I was trying to get a step-size with exact line search for a quadratic problem,e.g.$f(X) = \frac{1}{2}X^TQX$. I have used the same way as what has been done with gradient descent but replace the descent direction as $h=(\nabla ^{2} f(x))^{-1}\nabla f(x)$ in $\alpha = \frac{h^T QX}{h^TQh}$, but I found it turned out that the step-size is always 1, which seems to be nonsense. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

P.S. $f:\{\rm I\!R^n\rightarrow \rm I\!R \}$,$Q \in \rm I\!R ^{nxn}$.

Comment: I think you will need the Hessian to get a good direction. Is that what $\nabla ^{2}$ means in your notation?

Comment: sorry about the typo, I have changed it, $\nabla ^2 f(x)$ is the Hessian.

Comment: Then i think for a second degree polynomial you should by default get the right step size right away (if we can ignore measurement errors and other practicalities). Just as you would instantly correctly identify any second degree polynomial with a Taylor expansion around any point.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I used that stepsize in that algorithm, it turned out that it will arrive at the global minimum after only one iteration and I think it corresponds to why the exact step-size is 1.

Comment: yes, that is like I remembered it =)